# How do i save text into 2 different files?

Tags: python

I'm currently doing my GCSE in Computer Science and our task is to let people input their Surname and it saves it into two different files depending on the first letter in their Surname. The 2 files are Letters A-L (which they will save into with the correct first letter) but then the other text file is M-Z which doesn't seem to save anything when typing any letters in that range. How do I get it to save into 2 different files based off their first letter?

Here's what I have:

```
    MyFile1 = open("A-L.txt", "wt")
    MyFile2 = open("M-Z.txt", "wt")
    myList = ([])

    Surname = input("What is your surname");
    if Surname[0] in ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"]:
        myList.insert(2, Surname)
    for item in myList:
        MyFile1.write(item+"\n")
    if Surname[0] in ["M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]:
        MyFile2 = open("M-Z.txt", "wt")
        myList.insert(0, Surname)
    for item in myList:
    MyFile1.write(item+"\n")
```

Comment: You only write to the first file. Instead of opening the files in the `if` block, why not write in it? Also the indentation for your `for` loop is wrong.

Comment: Why go to all the trouble of adding the names to the lists, then writing the list to the file?  Do you use the lists somewhere later in your program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without all the list business:

```
MyFile1 = open("A-L.txt", "wt")
MyFile2 = open("M-Z.txt", "wt")

Surname = input("What is your surname");
if Surname[0] in ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"]:
    MyFile1.write(Surname + "\n")
if Surname[0] in ["M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"]:
    MyFile2.write(Surname + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just choose the appropriate file name?

```
A_TO_L = set("ABCDEFGHIJKL")

surname = input("What is your surname? ")

if surname[0] in A_TO_L:
    fname = "A-L.txt"
else:
    fname = "M-Z.txt"

with open(fname, "wt") as outf:
    outf.write("\n".join(mylist))
```